# Unable to add vector to FlatBuffer table (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatbuffers

I am following the [FlatBuffers Javascript tutorial](http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html) but I am having trouble adding a vector of non-scalar items to the following object:

```
namespace test;

enum Availability : byte {
  Unavailable = 0,
  Available = 1
}

table Channel {
  channelNumber:uint;
  myState:Availability = Unavailable;
}

table ControlChannel {
  channels:[Channel];
}

root_type ControlChannel;
```

As you can see the root object contains a vector of `Channel` objects. I successfully generated my javascript code, but while trying to create some test data it seems that the channels aren't added correctly. This is what I tried:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const flatbuffers = require('./flatbuffers').flatbuffers;
const test = require('./control-channel_generated').test;

// Create builder. The '1' is the 'initial size', whatever that means.
const builder = new flatbuffers.Builder(1);

// Create the first channel
test.Channel.startChannel(builder);
test.Channel.addChannelNumber(builder, 1);
const channel1 = test.Channel.endChannel(builder);

// Create another channel
test.Channel.startChannel(builder);
test.Channel.addChannelNumber(builder, 2);
test.Channel.addMyState(builder, test.Availability.Available);
const channel2 = test.Channel.endChannel(builder);

// Create a vector of the channels
const chans = [channel1, channel2];
const channels = test.ControlChannel.createChannelsVector(builder, chans);

// Create control channel and add the channels
test.ControlChannel.startControlChannel(builder);
test.ControlChannel.addChannels(builder, channels); // The resulting cc-test.data file is the same whether I comment this line or not
const controlChannel = test.ControlChannel.endControlChannel(builder);

// Control channel is finished
builder.finish(controlChannel);

// Create a buffer (to send it, write it etc)
const buf = builder.asUint8Array();
fs.writeFileSync('cc-test.data', buf);
console.log(`Data written to 'cc-test.data'.`);
```

This results in a file called `cc-test.data` which contains the buffer and no matter how many channels I try to add, the buffer is always exactly the same. I also tried parsing the data back like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const flatbuffers = require('./flatbuffers').flatbuffers;
const test = require('./control-channel_generated').test;

// Parse the data as a new byte array
const data = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync('./cc-test.data'));
const buf = new flatbuffers.ByteBuffer(data);

// This is where all the magic happens
const controlChannel = test.ControlChannel.getRootAsControlChannel(buf);

// You can not iterate over the channels directly, you have to get it by index
console.log(`ControlChannel has ${controlChannel.channelsLength()} channels:`);

for (var i = 0; i < controlChannel.channelsLength(); i++) {
  const channel = controlChannel.channels(i);
  console.log(`Channel ${channel.channelNumber()} (Available: ${channel.myState()})`);
}
```

This just prints *ControlChannel has 0 channels* every time. What am I missing?

Comment: The code looks correct to me. As an additional test, can you stick an int field with a very specific value (e.g. `123`, not as default value) in `ControlChannel`, and check that you can read it, just to verify the buffer is being read and written correctly?

Comment: Nope, i added `test:uint;` to the `ControlChannel` table and set it to `123`, but when reading it, it prints `0`. Meanwhile, the contents of the data file didn't change. It must be something in the writing process, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: Well, that means the problem isn't in the vector, but in the transmission/reading/writing of the file.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Comment: Looks like the default may be to write in text mode. Try passing it "wb" instead?